# EF Code first mapping view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use a EF code first  to create my system.

Recently I want to use it to map the view on SQL server , but it has problems

I create the model as the view name V_InProcessRMForm

This view is from the other dept. I have no right to change it and needn't .All I want is map the data from this view and show on the web page .

```
public class DmsEntity : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<V_InProcessRMForm> V_InProcessRMForm { get; set; }
}

public class V_InProcessRMForm
{
    [Key]
    public string Docid { get; set; }

    public string FormNm { get; set; }
    public string ChangeDocId { get; set; }
    public string Stats { get; set; }
    public string CancelReason { get; set; }
 }
```

when the code run here it display : you have no CREATE TABLE right ont it.

```
DmsEntity entity = new DmsEntity();
var l = from a in entity.V_InProcessRMForm
```

Has anyone can help me ? thanks a lot .

Comment: Error is quite clear. User identified in connection string does not have rights to create a table.

Comment: hi @PLB is mapping the view need the right to create table ?

Comment: It is clear that you are trying to create the database entities from your code first model and the EF is trying to create a table out of the view you are trying to map to.  You don't want it to try and create the database object as it already exists...

Comment: Hi @Penfold , How can I avoid or change code from the EF to create the table? Actually , I don't need to create it. I just want to use the data. thanks

Comment: That is what I mean, you don't want to create anything for this entity.  Are you running something that is trying to create the entities if they don't exist?  I'm not sure if there is something to prevent individual entities from being created.  You may need to create the tables via a script outside of the application and NOT add in anything for the view.

Comment: var l = context.database.SqlQuery<V_InProcessRMForm>("select * from V_InProcessRMForm"); This code should be in a repository based on EF.

Comment: Hi @Penfold In this case , i just new a entity instance and make a linq query,that's all, no more code a exist. Could u show me the detail mean Not add in anything for the view ? thx

Comment: Hi @tschmit007 thx
I try this before , but when i transto list() , it has the same error message ,too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I change the way , I use the normal EF to resolved this problem.
That generates the edmx file and I can use it accesses the view data now.

Thanks a lot.